# how to use django-newsletter app's views and forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, newsletter

I just installed [django-newsletter](https://django-newsletter.readthedocs.org) and so far all the tests did fine. But I'm not entirely sure how you can include a subscription form in my view so that subscribers can sign up. I created a Newsletter object called "Test" that is visible in the Admin.

Source Code of the views of django-newsletter app
https://github.com/dokterbob/django-newsletter/blob/master/newsletter/views.py

What I did was:

**in views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from newsletter.forms import SubscribeRequestForm

def landing(request):
    subscribeForm = SubscribeRequestForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {
        'subscribeForm': subscribeForm,
    }

    return render(request, "landing.html", context)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", 
line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",     
line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/src/Landing/views.py", line 12, in landing
subscribeForm = SubscribeRequestForm(request.POST or None)
File "/src/django-newsletter/newsletter/forms.py", line 18, in __init__
assert 'newsletter' in kwargs, 'No newsletter specified'
AssertionError: No newsletter specified
```

and when I change it to the following:

**in views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from newsletter.forms import SubscribeRequestForm

def landing(request):
    subscribeForm = SubscribeRequestForm(request.POST or None, newsletter="Test")

    context = {
        'subscribeForm': subscribeForm,
    }

    return render(request, "landing.html", context)
```

Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/src/Landing/views.py", line 10, in landing
subscribeForm = SubscribeRequestForm(request.POST or None, newsletter="Test")
File "/src/django-newsletter/newsletter/forms.py", line 30, in __init__
self.instance.newsletter = newsletter
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 207, in __set__
self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Test'": "Subscription.newsletter" must be a "Newsletter" instance.
```

**First Edit**

Following SO's suggestions
 I tried:

**in views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from newsletter.forms import SubscribeRequestForm
import newsletter

def landing(request):
    newsletter_obj = newsletter.objects.get(title="Test")
    subscribeForm = SubscribeRequestForm(request.POST or None, newsletter=newsletter_obj)

    context = {
        'subscribeForm': subscribeForm,
    }

    return render(request, "landing.html", context)
```

Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/src/Landing/views.py", line 9, in landing
newsletter_obj = newsletter.objects.get(title="Test")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that you need to assign `Newsletter` object, so you probably need to do the following:

```
newsletter = Newsletter.objects.get(title="Test")
subscribeForm = SubscribeRequestForm(request.POST or None, newsletter=newsletter)
```

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question but I tried that too, I get the "NameError: global name Test is not defined" (or newsletter following your code) error because I cannot import the newsletter object from admin to the view. It appears to be a package specific import. I reading the source code to figure out how.

Comment: Can you please show the full traceback of that error together with relevant code.